# Changes in XML file doesn't reflect in HTML Page

Tags: php, html, xml

I am creating a very small website that uses XML to store some infos in flat file (database not required). Right now everything works fine but every-time i update the XML file the changes wont reflect on page regardless of how many time i try to refresh the page or restart server. I am using "PHP XML DB" a class that makes CRUD easily possible with XML in PHP . The PHP class can be found at https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9314-PHP-Store-and-retrieve-data-records-in-XML-files.html#information.

Comment: My first thought was that the old file is in cache but restarting the server should clear that. The next thought is - are you putting the xml file into the correct place/folder?

Comment: Actually the class handles the creating and getting of all the XML File just like actual database but it has it's own caching method that only resets if the call is different from previously called. so to make a new cache i must call the new function from server or update the xml through the class instead of directly editing the xml file. for example

Comment: if $noteID is 12 display title, author, date.. the class will cache the query and result so it wont have to query again if same query is called again it just uses the cache that matches that query unless i update the xml using the class method provided .. manually editing the XML file will not affect the file and assumes the query and result is the same and displays the cache. so i have to clear the cache with method provided after every page load to get maximum dynamic result because the XML is updated from various sources and not just the class sometimes even manually .. thanks Jeff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found the solution, the class stores a cache after every different call and uses data from cache if the call is coming from client side, directly editing the XML file will not create a new cache therefore using the old cache.. My solution was to use an inbuilt but undocumented function to clear the cache at the end of every page call.. I fully depended on the documentation which i now realized it's not fully documented